# How do I write a type definition for a TypeScript library that only exposes one constructor function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, definitelytyped, .d.ts

I am trying to write a type definition for [this Splitwise NodeJS library](https://github.com/keriwarr/splitwise). I originally wrote something like this:

```js
declare module 'splitwise' {
    export function Splitwise(data: {
        consumerKey: string,
    }): SplitwiseObj;

    export class SplitwiseObj {
        public getCurrentUser(): Promise<SplitwiseUser>;
    }

    export interface SplitwiseUser {}
}
```

However, the library itself is actually a function. My type definition currently implies:

```js
const splitwise = require('splitwise');
const swObj = splitwise.Splitwise({consumerKey: ...})
```

while in reality it should be:

```js
const Splitwise = require('splitwise');
const swObj = Splitwise({consumerKey...});
```

How do I signal in a `.d.ts` file that the module being declared is itself a function?

Comment: Have you tried just `export default Splitwise;`? (and remove `export` from `export function Splitwise`)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `export interface SplitwiseUser {}` in your snippet with:

```
interface SplitwiseUser {}

export = SplitwiseUser;
```

From the [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require):

> Both CommonJS and AMD generally have the concept of an exports object which contains all exports from a module.
>
> They also support replacing the exports object with a custom single object. Default exports are meant to act as a replacement for this behavior; however, the two are incompatible. TypeScript supports `export =` to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow